# How to display html content through flask messages?

Tags: python, flask

I understand that `flash()` takes only string and displays that in the redirected page.
I m trying to send html through flash

```
message = "<h1>Voila! Platform is ready to used</h1>"
flash(message)
return render_template('output.html')
```

**output.html**

```
<div class="flashes">
  {% for message in get_flashed_messages()%}
    {{ message }}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

But it is displaying as string `<h1>Voila! Platform is ready to used</h1>` is there any way to overcome this.

Comment: please update the accepted answer, second answer is the right answer. @naga4ce

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Where possible, a secure approach is to [wrap your string in a Markup object before passing it to the template:](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#controlling-autoescaping)

**Python code:**

```
from flask import Markup

message = Markup("<h1>Voila! Platform is ready to used</h1>")
flash(message)
return render_template('output.html')
```

**Jinja2 Template:**

```
<div class="flashes">
  {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
    {{ message }}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Using `{{message|safe}}` will work, but also opens up the door for an attacker to inject malicious HTML or Javascript into your page, also known an an XSS attack. More info [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/security/#xss) if you're interested.

Comment: Excellent answer. `but there are still other places where you have to be careful: calling Markup on data submitted by users` found on the official document link. Can you explain this?

Comment: @arshovon Basically don't use Markup in places where users can enter their own data.

Answer (score 9):

Use the [`safe` filter](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#controlling-autoescaping):

```
<div class="flashes">
  {% for message in get_flashed_messages()%}
    {{ message|safe }}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: I would avoid delegating the escaping to template logic.

Comment: Applying `|safe` to all of your flashed messages is a *bad idea*: it opens your code to potential security vulnerabilities. Don't do this.

Answer (score 2):

For cases where you might want to control the CSS applied depending on the status of message (Success | Error), the following code might be useful:

```
{% for category, msg in get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}

    <div class="alert {{ category }} alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                           {{ msg|safe }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to call `render_template` to the external HTML file and passing that to `Markup` class.

**main/routes.py**

```py
from flask import render_template, flash, Markup
from . import blueprint

@blueprint.route("/user")
def user():
    flash(Markup(render_template("templates/user.html", name="John Doe"))
    return render_template("templates/home.html")
```

**templates/user.html**

```html
<h1>User: {{ name }}</h1>
```