# How to add a link to a text using Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

How can I add links to my text in Flask?

What I want to do is after submitting a form, I want to flash a message containing a link.

**I want to use Flask here.** But if this is something javascript can do I am also open to that.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Also this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/18225713/4046632

Comment: I'm not sure what "adding a link to text" means exactly and I'm not sure how that relates to flash messages.

Comment: what i mean is i have a flash message <p> in html. there i want to flash a message containing link. i would use href in html to do that but i dont know what to do in flask flash...